# Implementation of custom async task not working

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, handler

I am trying to create my own implementation of android Asynctask. For that I created an abstract class which extends Thread class. I declared methods for onPreExecute, onPostExecute, onProgressUpdate, and doInBackground.

I am running the doInBackground method by creating a handler from Looper of main thread. But I am unable to modify UI elements inside my onProgressUpdate() method but I am able to modify UI elements in onPostExecute() method.

Here is what I tried.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;

public abstract class MyAsyncTask extends Thread {
        String[] urls;
        Handler handler;

        abstract protected void onPreExecute();

        abstract protected void onPostExecute(String result);

        abstract protected void onProgressUpdate(String result);

        protected void publishProgress(String progress) {
            onProgressUpdate(progress);
        }

        abstract protected void doInBackground(String... urls);


        protected void execute(String... urls) {
            onPreExecute();
            this.urls = urls;
            start();
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        doInBackground(urls);
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

This is my MainActivity. It has progress bar and progressText to show progress.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressBar bar;
    TextView progressText;
    LinearLayout container;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bar = findViewById(R.id.progress);
        progressText = findViewById(R.id.progressText);
        container = findViewById(R.id.container);
    }

    public void startProcess(View view) {
        String[] assignments = {"assgn1", "assgn2", "assgn3", "assgn4", "assgn5"};

        new ProgressAsync().execute(assignments);
    }

    public void showProgress() {
        container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void hideProgress() {
        container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public class ProgressAsync extends MyAsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            showProgress();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            progressText.setText("All processed");
            hideProgress();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String result) {
            progressText.setText(result + "  processed");
        }

        @Override
        protected void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            for (int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                publishProgress(this.urls[i]);
            }
            onPostExecute("SUCCESS");
        }
    }


}
```

It supposed to set progressText like assgn1, assgn2 etc after every 2 seconds. But it doesn't set any text for progressText during onProgressUpdate(), but sets "All Processed" in onPostExecute() method.

Can someone help me if I am missing something here.

Comment: you makes `MyAsyncTask extends Thread`. Thread is not AsyncTask. You need `MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>`

Comment: @anatoli I don't want to create a subclass of AsyncTask. I want to implement a version of AsyncTask itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some rules that you need to know before implementing your own [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows you to perform background operations and publish results on the
>   UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

1. AsyncTask will spawn at least one background thread to do its work.
2. `doInBackground()` will run on this background thread, because if it runs on the UI thread, your app will freeze or even get crash.
3. `onPreExecute()`, `onPostExecute()`, `onProgressUpdate()` will run on UI thread.

In your code, because the code in `doInBackground()` run on UI thread, that why your app get freeze, until it reaches the last line in the `doInBackground()` method.

Here is my solution:

**MyAsyncTask.java**

```
public abstract class MyAsyncTask extends Thread {
    private String[] mUrls;
    private Handler mMainHandler;

    public MyAsyncTask() {
        // Using this handler to update UI
        mMainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    abstract protected void onPreExecute();

    abstract protected void onPostExecute(String result);

    abstract protected void onProgressUpdate(String result);

    protected void publishProgress(final String progress) {
        // This will run in UI thread.
        mMainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                onProgressUpdate(progress);
            }
        });
    }

    abstract protected String doInBackground(String... urls);

    protected void execute(String... urls) {
        mUrls = urls;
        start();
    }

    public void run() {
        // This will run in UI thread.
        mMainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                onPreExecute();
            }
        });

        String result = null;
        try {
            // This will run in the background thread.
            result = doInBackground(mUrls);
        } finally {
            // This will run in UI thread.
            final String finalResult = result;
            mMainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    onPostExecute(finalResult);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**ProgressAsync.java**

```
public class ProgressAsync extends MyAsyncTask {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        showProgress();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progressText.setText(result);
        hideProgress();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String result) {
        progressText.setText(result + "  processed");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        for (String url : urls) {
            publishProgress(url);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

**Note:** I just give the simple and quick solution, In practice, you need to write more code to handle some scenarios, such as handling exceptions, cancelling the background tasks, etc.

Comment: Thanks Nhất Giang. Now I know what I was missing.